# "Affine Variety" versus "Variety"

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In Mumford's Red Book, a distinction seems to be made between the terms *affine* variety and variety. The term *variety* seems to be defined by something called the Hausdorff. I was wondering if anyone could clarify these terms.

Comment: Your question does not seem to be complete.

Comment: What was probably meant is that "varieties" were assumed to be separated.

(In EGA, "scheme" used to mean what today we would call a separated scheme)

Comment: (separated is the "hausdorff" condition in algebraic geometry)

Comment: The class of varieties strictly contains that of affine varieties. They are (locally) ringed spaces locally isomorphic to affine varieties and satisfying the additional global condition of separateness — this is usually used to ensure that maps defined on dense opens extend uniquely if they extend at all.